# Postgres SQL syntax error near invisible 'REFERENCES'?

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax-error

I am trying to create two tables with the following code.

```
CREATE TABLE assessments (
  id INT UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(100),
  type VARCHAR(10),
  total_points NUMERIC,
  weight NUMERIC
  CHECK(weight >= 0)
  CHECK(weight <= 100),
  due_date DATE,
  section_id INT REFERENCES sections(id)
);

CREATE TABLE enrollment_assessments (
  id INT UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES enrollments(id),
  assignment_id REFERENCES assignments(id),
  assessment_type REFERENCES assessments(type),
  points NUMERIC
    CHECK (points >= 0)
    CHECK (points <-100),
);
```

However, I get the error :

> [Code: , SQL State: 42601]  ERROR: syntax error at or near
>   "REFERENCES"   Position: 112

which is saying the error is near the first line of code? I don't understand this error at all.

Answer (score 0):

I do not like the comma in this part:

```
CHECK (points >= 0)
CHECK (points <-100),
```

Comment: oops yea! but it still has done nothing to fix the error. even when i comment out the first few lines of code it still gives me an error on the commented part? this db stuff is very confusing

Answer (score 0):

you miss data types and extra comma has to be removed:

```
 CREATE TABLE enrollment_assessments (
  id INT UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES enrollments(id),
  assignment_id INT REFERENCES assignments(id),
  assessment_type VARCHAR(10) REFERENCES assessments(type),
  points NUMERIC
    CHECK (points >= 0)
    CHECK (points <-100)
);
```